# C++ - problems with vector pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

Imagine I want to manipulate a single vector with the content of two current vectors, such as:

```
vector<double> b(5),c(5);
vector<double*> point;  

for (int i; i<5; i++) point.push_back(new double(b[i]));
for (int i; i<5; i++) point.push_back(new double(c[i]));
```

That's nice until here. How would one manipulate such vector?
I have been trying variations of:

```
point[7] = 33.12;
```

I am pretty sure I am missing something about reference since "point[7]" will be a memory address.

Comment: `for (int i; i<5; i++)` is bad because `i` is used without being initialized.

Comment: why not `vector<double> point;` ?

Comment: just asking because I was afraid you want to store pointers to elements in the other vectors. This would invite a whole class of other issues. You arent doing that but then I wonder why use pointers in the first place

Comment: This will be implemented in a function of a class to be used as argument to another function. So, it will make way simpler if I could pass a vector of pointers having the references of multiple vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a `vector` of pointers, the subscript operator **returns a pointer**:

```
*point[0] = 33.12; // Assigns new value to the pointer
// Equivalent: *(point[0]), fetch a pointer and dereference it
```

For example:

```
vector<double*> point; 
double d = 3.14;
point.push_back(&d);
*point[0] = 1.61;
std::cout << *point[0] << std::endl; // Prints 1.61
```

P.S. as specified in comments to the question, note the: `int i` in your `for` loop.

Comment: _"Since you this is"_ is a typo, I presume?

Comment: @DrewDormann true! missed the edit due to being editing. Will fix now. Thank you!

Comment: Worked! Thank you sir. I gotta wait for a couple minutes to accept your answer.

Comment: @Pedro All good! Feel free to ask for clarifications (if any are required).